# Sequelize does not allow to insert new row into database

Tags: sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sql-insert

I have the following 2 tables called Employee and Department:

```
const Employee = connection.define('Employee', {
    employeeNum: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    SSN: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressStreet: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressCity: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressState: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressPostal: Sequelize.STRING,
    isManager: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    employeeManagerNum: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    status: Sequelize.STRING,
    department: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    hireDate: Sequelize.STRING,
    maritalStatus: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Department = connection.define('Employee', {
departmentId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},
departmentName: Sequelize.STRING
```

})

And the form to add a new employee:

### Add Employee

```
            <br />
    
            <form method="post" action="/employees/add">
    
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="SSN">Social Security Num:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="SSN" name="SSN" type="text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="addressStreet">Address (Street):</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="addressStreet" name="addressStreet" type="text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="addressCity">Address (City):</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="addressCity" name="addressCity" type="text"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="addressState">Address (State):</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="addressState" name="addressState" type="text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="addressPostal">Address (Zip Code):</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="addressPostal" name="addressPostal" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
    
                </fieldset>
    
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Company Information</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="isManager">Manager:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="isManager" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="employeeManagerNum">Employee's Manager Number:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="employeeManagerNum" name="employeeManagerNum" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Status:</label><br />
                                <label  class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="statusFT" name="status" value="Full Time" /> Full Time
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="statusFT" name="status" value="Part Time" /> Part Time
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="department">Department</label>
                                {{#if departments}}
                                    <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department">
                                        {{#each departments}}
                                            <option value="{{departmentId}}">{{departmentName}}</option>
                                        {{/each}}
                                    </select>
                                {{else}}
                                        <div>No Departments</div>
                                {{/if}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="hireDate">Hire Date</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="hireDate" name="hireDate" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </fieldset>
    
                <hr />
    
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Add Employee" /><br /><br /><br />
    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This view is rendered by this GET handler:

```
app.get('/employees/add', async (req, res) => {
let departments;
try {
    departments = await dataService.getDepartments();
}
catch(err) {
    departments = [];
}

res.render('addEmployee', {departments})
```

})

And the submission of form is handled by this POST handler:

```
app.post('/employees/add', (req, res) => {
dataService.addEmployee(req.body)
.then(() => res.redirect('/employees'))
.catch((err) => res.status(500).send(err))
```

})

However, when I try to add a new employee to my database, I get {} empty object as response. Why is this happening? dataService functions which I use here:

```
function getDepartments() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Department.findAll()
    .then(data => resolve(data))
    .catch(() => reject('no results'))
})
```

}

```
function addEmployee(employeeData) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        employeeData.isManager = employeeData.isManager ? true : false;
        employeeData.maritalStatus = '';
        for (const attr in employeeData) {
            if (employeeData[attr] == "") {
                employeeData[attr] = null;
            }
        }

        Employee.create(employeeData)
        .then(() => resolve())
        .catch((err) => reject(err))
})
```

}

Comment: *"I get {} empty object as response."* - i wish to clarify, this "response" refers to http response?

Comment: I don't see the handler for `/employees`

Comment: You do not need to see /employees handler, because I get the catch block working in /employees/add post handler. It sends {} as res.status(500).send(err)

Answer (score 0):

When defining models for Department and Employee, I accidentally wrote 'Employee' when defining model for Department. kekw